# Java JSON writes double

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a java object to JSON object with the code below and I recognized that the parameters which start with upper case has been written double. For example;

```
Request req = new Request();
req.setMAC("abcdef");
req.setMACParams("term:id:orderno");
req.setOrderNo("999xdef123");

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(req);
```

Inside of json string:

```
{ "MAC":"abcdef","MACParams":"term:id:orderno","OrderNo":"999xdef123","mac":"abcdef","macparams":"term:id:orderno","orderno":"999xdef123" }
```

So what should i do to prevent this double code?

Comment: hmm java is case sensitive, `MAC` is different from `mac`... not sure what the question is...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686018/1927832

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. We cant see your code if you don't post it. And the few lines you posted isn't even valid Java code.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post confidential code so that I put an example code. I think my question is clear to understand and doesn't matter wheter it is valid or not because it's so simple but i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs due to upper case letters used in field property names.
Just use `@JsonProperty` annotation in each field of Request class then it will de-serialize to given name only.

E.g.:

```
class Request{
    @JsonProperty("MAC")
    private String mac;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have getter & setter in your class Request, but those getter does not follow java bean rules, 
The field "MAC" whith getMAC and setMAC whill be correct , but "getMac" will generate mac twice in the result.